# How to show split vr mode in A-Frame when using desktop without connected to VR Headsets

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am new in A-Frame.

How to show split/stereo VR mode on desktop without connected to VR headsets like this example?

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_effects_stereo

Do I have to modify the code in aframe.js, or create a own component?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It is not possible without some work on A-Frame itself. Stereo rendering only triggers when a headset is present. What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has an extension called WebVR API Emulator worth taking a look at. It simply emulates a split screen as it would be seen in a VR headset.